# Gitkraken sing in problem with GitHub Account ( Could not Connect to Server)

Tags: authentication, github

I have installed the [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) form the Ubuntu Software android App, But for connecting to GitHub Servers i get the below error:

```
**Could not connect to server**
```

[image]

But for trying to signing by the google account, it gives the Token form chrome Browser but it is not working on the **GitKaraken** singing page!.

So what could be the reason for this problem?

Update:

I guess this is Because of the sanction restriction for the ISP and my country location!

I have turned off the VPN from the Chrome extension and by clicking on the google signing i get this error:

```
403 Forbidden
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: From what I can see in the pictures, you are not signing in with GitHub, but trying to sign in to your GitKraken account. I would recommend pushing the blue "Sign In with GitHub" button ...

Comment: I have pushed that button and it is not working and give the above error (**Could not connect to server!**)